# dnf info results in "Installed Packages", what does the color of the Name signify?

Tags: fedora

in the console do

```
$  dnf  info *mesa*
..
and you should see result like
..
Installed Packages
Name         : mesa-dri-drivers
Version      : 21.1.8
```

The Name  : xxxxxxx  is normally shown in a bluish text color.
Now it shows for example mesa-dri-drivers, in yellow-orangle (bold?)
what is this different color trying to tell me
and
if you know the answer, where, where is it documented ? whatever this color legend is supposed
to be?
PS.i don't think whatever fedora version is, is relevant.
Thankyou